# Grouping results from UNION Result

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the messages from a table:

```
  (SELECT 'MesRec' as Type, u.UserID, u.Name, u.TeamID, max(m.Message) as Message, sum(case when m.DateRead is null then 1 else 0 end) Qty, DateSent
  FROM Messages m
  JOIN Users u on u.UserID = m.UserFrom
  WHERE m.UserTo = 5
  GROUP BY m.UserFrom
  ORDER BY m.DateSent DESC)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT 'MesSen' as Type, u.UserID, u.Name, u.TeamID, max(m.Message) as Message, sum(case when m.DateRead is null then 1 else 0 end) Qty, DateSent
  FROM Messages m
  JOIN Users u on u.UserID = m.UserTo
  WHERE m.UserFrom = 5
  GROUP BY m.UserTo
  ORDER BY m.DateSent DESC)
ORDER BY DateSent
```

Which is returning the data exactly like I'd expect, however... I'd like to merge data where the UserID matches. I've tried adding a GROUP BY on u.UserID after the UNION, but to no prevail!

Currently I'll get the result of:

```
MesRec | 4 | Mr D | 4 | Test Message | 1
MesRec | 1 | Mr A | 1 | Test Message | 0
MesSen | 2 | Mr B | 2 | Test Message | 0
MesSen | 4 | Mr D | 4 | Test Message | 0
```

Comment: Please add the table and data scripts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrap the UNION result up as a subquery in the FROM clause of an outer query, and apply the ORDER BY to the outer query only:

```
SELECT tmp.* FROM (
  (SELECT 'MesRec' as Type, u.UserID, u.Name, u.TeamID, max(m.Message) as Message, sum(case when m.DateRead is null then 1 else 0 end) Qty, DateSent
  FROM Messages m
  JOIN Users u on u.UserID = m.UserFrom
  WHERE m.UserTo = 5
  GROUP BY m.UserFrom
)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT 'MesSen' as Type, u.UserID, u.Name, u.TeamID, max(m.Message) as Message, sum(case when m.DateRead is null then 1 else 0 end) Qty, DateSent
  FROM Messages m
  JOIN Users u on u.UserID = m.UserTo
  WHERE m.UserFrom = 5
  GROUP BY m.UserTo
) tmp
ORDER BY tmp.DateSent
```